# Look for text in a div that has multiple links under it with Watir

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, watir

I am trying to verify that the text of a link is present in a . The div is not available until a link is clicked. After the link is click more links become available to click. Below is what the html looks like after the click to expose the other links.

```
<div class="more-links">
   <a href="url">First Link</a>
   <a href="url">Second Link</a>
   <a href="url">Third Link</a>
   <a href="url">Fourth Link</a>
   <a href="url">Fifth Link</a>
</div>
```

I want to find make sure the text "Third Link" is there after the div appears.

I have tried, but watir is saying that it cannot find that element.

```
assert_equal(true, browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link"))
```

I can find the text with this but is really slow and want to specify this particular div

```
browser.text.include?("Third Link")
```

Thoughts?

Comment: if you are using cucumber, why are you using assert and not .should?

Comment: `browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link").should exist`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This following code isn't going to return `true`:

```
browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link")
#=> #<Watir::Link:0x..f99c8864c located=false specifiers={:tag_name=>["a"], :text=>"Third Link"}>
```

So, the `assert_equal` is returning false.

If `exists?` is appended to that line, then it returns `true`:

```
browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link").exists?
#=> true
```

Comment: #a actually returns a Watir::Anchor object for me (different watir-webdriver versions?), but in any case it certainly isn't the boolean true.

Comment: Good point.  I was using watir-classic, which returns a `Watir::Link` as opposed to a `Watir::Anchor` object in watir-webdriver.

Comment: There is more than one class with the same name, I think that is why watir cannot find the element.
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean there is more than one Div with that class?  in that case you will need to add an additional qualifier, such as Index, or start with a unique container that holds the div..   Showing us more of the HTML might help in that case

Answer (score 0):

> browser.text.include?("Third Link")
>
> I can find the text with this but is really slow and want to specify
>   this particular div

...which is exactly what you did here:

```
browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link")
```

So in your original line of code, you just need to replace 'browser' with your more specific search:

```
browser.div(:class => "more-links").a(:text => "Third Link")
```

Also note, that you would never write:

```
assert_equal(true, ...)
```

because you can save yourself some typing and just write:

```
assert(...)
```